# How to edit the view of showing products in Zen Cart?

Tags: zen-cart

I have a category of products named "Fashion & Jewellery,Bag" and it has two sub categories "For Man" and "For woman" and these two sub categories also have some sub categories.

http://24sevensale.com.au/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=66

Now I want to do to view the sub categories of Man and Woman in a same page and the sub catagories of Man and Woman will be only hyperlinked.

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create one or more customized pages as the product category pages display one category per page. Zen cart has a override system that allows customization outside of the core files which you would want to use so that you can update the core if needed without overwriting your customizations. It's described here: http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?228-understanding-the-override-system